# Increase the font size based on the size of the device

Tags: android, textview

I planned to use different font size for the textview on different device size so as to make the letters legible. I have already decided not to use different layouts for different devices and built a common layout to fit in all the devices. Now the only problem is on the text size.

Questions :

1. I would like to have your technical suggestions on how to alter the font size based on the size (the physical size) of the device.
2. How to derive the font size based on the aspect ratio.
3. Any Flaws in using this kind of approach ?

Xml for the text view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValue4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I planned to use different font size for the textview on different device size so as to make the letters legible. I have already decided not to use different layouts for different devices and built a common layout to fit in all the devices. Now the only problem is on the text size."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28):

Yes, this approach is flawed. Android devices have different sizes, but they can also have very different densities as well.

[image]

You should just be following the Android design [best practices](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html).

[image]

They're actually very well thought out. Why would you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: http://picpaste.com/Untitled1-4MSIpnIo.png  Please check out the screen shot I have used the 15dp for the textview. But this is shown in different number of lines in different devices. I need to have all the screens with the same number of lines. If the screen size small the font has to be small and If the screen size in big then the font has to turn big.. Please pass your suggestions

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html  A `dp` is a density-independent pixel that corresponds to the physical size of a pixel at 160 dpi. An `sp` is the same base unit, but is scaled by the user's preferred text size (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes).

Answer (score 23):

Try this, Add this attribute in your xml. It will adjust textsize based on screensize try it.

```
 style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
```

Comment: This is available from API 14.. I am using the min API 8

Comment: where exactly do I have to put this? in parent layout or to the component?

Answer (score 5):

For font sizes use scale pixels (sp). Android will scale the font size accordingly depending on the device density. Above posts have a better explanation and the reasoning.

Comment: I changed to sp. but still the same problem. basically I need to make this textview to occupy same % of the screen in all devices and fill it with text

Comment: are u setting the fontsizes programmatically or from xml ?

Comment: try doing it programmatically by calculating the device density and the appropriate font size you want to set. int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, <HEIGHT>, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());  You can check Complex_unit_sp too.

Comment: int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, <HEIGHT>, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());                                   You can set the <HEIGHT> anything which is appropriate for you for testing. EX: textView.setTextSize(height);

Answer (score 1):

For API 26 and higher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

Source:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Answer (score 0):

Android has built in facilities for this-  dp and sp.  dp is device pixels.  It basically is 1dp=1/160th of an inch.  This allows you to specify the height of the font in real world size.  Sp is scaled pixels.  This size scales based on the default font size, so a user can scale up his system font and your app will match it.  Handy for people with sight problems who need big text, while not taking up screen real estate for others.

You should probably be using one or the other of these.

Comment: picpaste.com/Untitled1-4MSIpnIo.png Please check out the screen shot I have used the 15dp for the textview. But this is shown in different number of lines in different devices. I need to have all the screens with the same number of lines. If the screen size small the font has to be small and If the screen size in big then the font has to turn big.. Please pass your suggestions – iappmaker

Comment: dp (or dip) is Device-Independent Pixels, not "device pixels". See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension The rest of your post about 160 dots per inch and everything else is mostly correct. I'm just being pedantic.

Answer (score 0):

for this issue I am using following library in so many projects and believe this is fantastic. No need to worry about screens. But again you need to create separate layouts for tabs.

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

### Font size based on the screen size

```
public static void applyFont(TextView tv, Float fontSize) {
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, fontSize * fontFactor);
}

public static float fetchFontFactor(Activity act) {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    float returnFactor = ((float) displayMetrics.widthPixels ) / 1280.0f;

    return returnFactor;
}
```

In MainActiviy.java I have

```
fontFactor = fetchFontFactor(this);
```

Now the question is, what is 1280 in my code.

Answer is this is nothing but the width of the design that the designer provides. E.x. If the designer gives a design of size 1080x1920, you can replace 1280 with 1080.

So if a designer has a font of 55 in the design, we can use 55 as below.

```
applyFont(titleTV, 55f);
```

### This works for both orientation...