# What is the point of textAppearance?

Tags: android, xml

I want to make an xml file with text that looks at least kind of similar on all devices, given solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715324/increase-the-font-size-based-on-the-size-of-the-device) I understood that I can use sp, or textAppearance and let it  rescale based on the screen.

So I tried it, on eclipse its shown like that:
[image]

and on tablet emulator like that:

[image]

At least from what I can see, the size didn't change at all although the screen has grown, why? and what can I do to make it look similar on all devices, I don't understand how textview scaling works..

here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Edit:

Same story about SP:
[image]

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:gravity="top"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:text="100sp"
    android:textSize="100sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="15SP"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

It is the same size, on different screens!

Comment: please mention what are the density value of your mobile emulator & tablet emulator.

Comment: You confuse size and resolution. A flexible UI has to be size-based. If I have a 5" screen at 480x360 resolution, I want a "large" text to appear that same as on a 5" screen at 1280x800. If it didn't scale that, then text on the higher-resolution screen would be too small to read, buttons too small to tap, etc. If you make something 160dp, it will always be one inch in size, regardless of screen size and resolution. You are free to create different styles and layouts for different screen sizes.

Comment: @AmitK.Saha How do I get that?

Comment: @323go I understand, but that means I need to create many different styles for different devices? where does it end? also how do I differ from a device to device, how do I know what to use and when?

Comment: I don't think you understand. If I use your app on a larger screen, I want to see *more* information. I don't want to see the *same* information, only larger. It's going to make your UI awkward, if not painful, to use. If that seems like too much work, you can always calculate the relative sizes at runtime.

Comment: @323go Ohh, now I see the logic behind that. But what if I have a still screen and I want to display small amount of information at once in the biggest size possible? how do I do that?

Comment: @SpoocyCrep, in that case, you can determine the screen-size from `WindowManager` and set up your font-size programmatically in `onCreate()`. If you google those terms, you should find several duplicate answers here on SO.

Comment: @323go OK. that is a lot of work.. is that the same thing about buttons? I need to set everything by looking at the size and calculating everything?

Comment: @SpoocyCrep, yeah , the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to define your own styles in styles.xml. That, in my view is better than relying solely on the default themes. They do change from manufacturer to manufacturer. Your idea is true only in cases of devices using the stock Android OS.

And they are not the equal size. If you look at the `styles.xml` in the `sdk\platforms\android-4.3\data\res\values\` you would be able to see that.

Comment: But if I define my own style it still wont matter, Ill define it with SP, and SP still doesn't look the same on every device..

Comment: SP will never be same size. And thats the benefit. It will be scaled up or down according to density. e.g. difference in percentage would be same across all the device between a 15sp text & a 11sp text.

Comment: @AmitK.Saha, `sp` is generally the same as `dp`, unless the user chose a larger or smaller font-size system-wide.

Comment: @323go, surely they are same. the difference can be seen if user changes font scale from device settings.