# Appium : Android getPageSource Issue

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium

I have a scenario where i will have to get the page source of the entire page. But in android (using appium) when I use `getPageSource`, only the elements that are visible in front end is returned, not the entire page(I need to scroll down to get other elements in that page). This is not the case in iOS, it will return all the elements whether it is visible or not in that page. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

that is android behaviour, ive got a workaround for it

go to

> settings>Display>Font size>choose the smallest

then issue `driver.getpagesource()`; in ur script

Comment: Thank you karthick23...is there any java code through which Font size can be reduced?

Comment: no, not directly, may be this will give an idea why, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715324/increase-the-font-size-based-on-the-size-of-the-device